# Export author mapping in Stash SVN Mirror

Tags: git, svn, bitbucket-server, subgit

I am building a Stash server to migrate our SVN projects to Git.

Currently I am experimenting with trial Stash and SVN Mirror plugin for importing some of our projects.

The point is the following: while LDAP mapping is working and commits have always been consistent with the users, some people that left the company are no more registered in our LDAP, so I decided to manually type their old email for sake of completeness into the Git Author mapping screen that appears when I prepare the project for importing.

Since it's repeated work, I would like to **export** an author mapping file for the missing entried to import in the plugin's global configuration screen.

The question is:

Do you know how can I export an SVN<->Git authors file from either an existing Git repository made in Stash by an SVN import or *during* the wizard itself? It could be very useful

Comment: Clarification: I want to export the data I have entered into Stash (the data Stash couldn't auto detect)

Answer (score 0):

There's no UI option to export authors mapping file, however, you can find this file on Stash server at the following location:

```
STASH_HOME/shared/data/repositories/REPO_ID/subgit/authors.txt
```

Make sure that corresponding Git repository is an active mirror. You can find a path to this Git repository on Repository Settings | Repository Details page.